# Override a class in Bukkit API

Tags: java, plugins, overriding, minecraft, bukkit

I want to override one class in the Bukkit api with my plugin. I know it's NOT IMPOSSIBLE, because PEX developers does it.

Here is the link: https://github.com/PEXPlugins/PermissionsEx/blob/master/src/main/java/ru/tehkode/permissions/bukkit/regexperms/PermissiblePEX.java

I'd like to know, what is the simplest working way to do it.

Comment: The link you provided doesn't show any class overriding, the class only uses reflection to change a private field. Unless you meant extending, not overriding.

Comment: I need this too. I think the word to use is not override, but replace a method so if a reference was made to hasPermission() it'd go to our custom made hasPermission(). @gyurix did you find a solution?

Comment: No I didn´t find it, I only found a way for replaceing the private variables in the class, but not the methods, what I need to replace.

Comment: @gyurix That's unfortunate.. i'm writing a permissions plugin and permissions change as per location. Guess I'll just have to change permissions on Player Move then (which is terrible).

Comment: I'm done with that. I didn‘t change permissions on player move, I only test permissions with given Location or with actuall player location. So I created a new class for this data, which contains the accepted regions, global and per region expiration, but it also contains some methods for testing the authenticity with expiration calculation of the permission at the given place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the way in the PEX and I simplified it:

First I need to declare a Field variable:

```
public static Field mezo;
```

After that, at OnEnable method I need to get CraftHumanEntitys perm field:

```
try{
mezo=Class.forName("org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R1.entity.CraftHumanEntity").getDeclaredField("perm");
}
catch(Throwable h){
}
```

And at every player join I need to register the player:

```
Jogkezelheto uj=new Jogkezelheto(j);
try{
    mezo.setAccessible(true);
    mezo.set(j,uj);
}
catch (Throwable h){
}
```

Jogkezelheto is my class, which extends the PermissibleBase, such as the PermissiblePex is PEX. And it's working!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that when you say "override" you mean "extend". If that's correct, Java has a nice fancy keyword for that:

```
public class MyBukkitClass extends BukkitClass {
...
}
```

This gives you access to all the methods/variables that were in that original BukkitClass that you are extending.

If you look in that class you posted in github, the extends keyword is used on line 52. An example of constructing a class that you are extending is shown on line 77.

Comment: @gyurix, I know this is the first question you've asked on stack overflow so, just to inform you, the proper process once someone has given an answer that you used is to upvote and checkmark their answer so they get points :-). Hope this helped you.

Comment: OK, I know that, but this simple extending only copies the class, but not replaces it. So I have to "load this class" and replace it with this "extended" class.

Comment: So you want to have your class be called instead of the existing class? Is that right?

Comment: Yes, I exactly want this.